# PEAR configuration in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Does any one know how to configure PEAR in Zend framework. I installed pear through terminal.And i call it in zend library require_once 'PEAR/Exception.php'; it doesn't work.Please help

Comment: Make sure PEAR is on your PHP include_path and it should work.